# Spring - how to inject a bean into class which is created many times at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I needed to initialize a bean at the application startup so I did that in `applicationContext.xml`. But now I need to inject that bean into an object which is created at runtime. Example:

`Servlet`

```
...
void doPost(...) {
    new Handler(request); 
}
...
```

`Handler`

```
public class Handler {

    ProfileManager pm; // I need to inject this ???

    Handler(Request request) {
        handleRequest(request);
    }

    void handleRequest(Request request) {
        pm.getProfile(); // example
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better approach would be to declare the Handler as Bean as well - assuming that the ProfileManager is already declared - and then autowire the ProfileManager in the Handler bean either with the annotation @Autowired if you are using annotations in your apps, or inside the applicationContext.xml.
An example of how to do it in the xml could be:

```
<bean id="profileManager" class="pckg.ProfileManager" />
<bean id="handler" class="pckg.Handler" >
 <property name="pm" ref="profileManager" />
</bean>
```

If you do NOT want to register Handler as bean instantiate it as you do and take the pm instance from spring's ApplicationContext. A way of how to get ApplicationContext inside a web app is shown [here](http://blog.jdevelop.eu/?p=154)

Comment: Good point. I was thinking about it and decided to create the Handler only once as you say. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Declare `Handler` and `ProfileManager` as a spring  bean , initialize them lazily. and inject them don't use `new Handler()` let Spring do this

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wonder why "Handler" is intilialized over and over again. Using a bean and calling a method multiple times at runtime seems to be just as good in this example.

Apart from that, you can use an aspect that is a bean itself. Inject the ProfileManager there and let the Aspect work on creation of Handler, setting the pm.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers stating that you really should let Spring handle the creation of `Handler` but if that isn't an option then you could inject `ProfileManager` into `Servlet` and then just pass it into the constructor when you create `Handler`.